# Customizing the user model: how to show related info in the admin

Tags: django, django-admin

**Django 1.10.2**

Studying customization of the User model.

Trying to follow the documentaion https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model

I wish to store that department and show it in the admin.
The problem is that department doesn't appear.

I played with fieldsets and list_display, but failed.

Could you help me understand how to show the department in the admin?

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=100)


# Define an inline admin descriptor for Employee model
# which acts a bit like a singleton
class EmployeeInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Employee
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'employee'

# Define a new User admin
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    inlines = (EmployeeInline, )

# Re-register UserAdmin
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Comment: you have a one-to-one relationship between Employee and User - django will only show one-to-many relationships (foreign keys) in inlines

Comment: Well, this example is from the documentation. Where it is mentioned that we can add this department to the admin. And the example is given. The very example we can see here.